# How to solve the undefined index error when adding the selected quantity of each registration type to the array?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to get the quantity of each registration type with the code below:

```
$registrationTypeDetails = Registration::with('participants:id,registration_type_id,registration_id')->find($regID);

$type_counts = [];
foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
    $name = $p->registration_type->name;
    if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
        $type_counts[$name] = 0;
    }
    $type_counts[$name]++;
}
```

The `dd($type_counts)`, if the conference has 2 registration types available (general and plus) and the user is doing a registration with 2 registration types "**general**" and 0 of registration type "**plus**" shows:

```
 array:2 [▼
      "general" => 2
    ]
```

So it's working fine. But then I need to make a post request to an API where is necessary to send in the request body the quantity of each registration type, in this case for the registration type "**general**" the value should be "2".

But it's not working properly, it appears `"Undefined index: plus"`.

Do you know where is the issue?

```
    foreach($registration->conference->registrationTypes as $key=>$registrationType){
       $items['invoice']['items'][]  = [
   'name' => $registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['name'],
   'unit_price' => $registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['price'],
   'quantity' =>  $type_counts[$registration->conference->registrationTypes[$key]['name']], // error is here
            ];
        }

        $create = $client->request('POST', 'https://...', [
            'query' => ['api_key' => '...'], 'json' => $items,
        ]);
```

The array with items should be like:

```
 array:1 [▼
  "invoice" => array:4 [▼
    "items" => array:2 [▼
      0 => array:5 [▼
        "name" => "general"
        "unit_price" => 10
        "quantity" => 2
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

The `dd($registration->conference->registrationTypes)` is showing the two registration types that are associated with the conference (general and plus):

```
Collection {#337 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => RegistrationType {#330 ▼
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:11 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "general"
        ...
      ]
    }
    1 => RegistrationType {#345 ▼
      #attributes: array:11 [▼
        "id" => 2
        "name" => "plus"
        ...
      ]
        ...
    }
  ]
}
```

The issue is when is not selected any registraiton type "plus". If the user only select registration types of type"general" it appears the "Undefined index: plus" but if the user selects registration types "general" but also "plus" the error dont appears. For example if the $type_counts is like below the error dont appears:

```
array:1 [▼
  "geral" => 2,
  "plus"  => 1
]
```

Comment: You wrote `geral` instead of `general`

Comment: Thanks, I update the question to correct that.

Comment: you only fixed the question or also fixed the database? Or was this just a copy-paste error?

Comment: Why aren't you using `groupBy("name")` and `count()`?

Comment: Yes, in the db is also "general". Use group by and count instead of "$type_counts = [];
foreach ($registrationTypeDetails->participants as $p) {
    $name = $p->registration_type->name;
    if (!isset($type_counts[$name])) {
        $type_counts[$name] = 0;
    }
    $type_counts[$name]++;
}"?

Comment: The issue is when is not seleected any registraiton type "plus". If the user only select registration types of type"general" it appears the "Undefined index: plus" but if the user selects registration types "general" but also "plus" the error dont appears.